# Rotate character towards the direction of the camera?

Tags: c#, vector, 3d, unity-game-engine

I want to rotate the character towards the direction the camera is pointing.

In the screenshot below, the red ray is the direction from the camera to the character and the green one the direction the camera is pointing.

[image]

Basically the character line of sight should remain perpendicular to the red vector but pointing to the end of the green one.

This is what I'm trying now. I managed to get the direction the player should rotate towards, as seen on this screenshot. The green ray is it's vision and the blue ray, the direction I would like him to face.

```
    // Result vector
    Vector3 directionCam = CameraDirection (transform.position);

    // Show current forward and desired forward
    Debug.DrawRay(character.transform.position, character.transform.forward, Color.green); // Vision
    Debug.DrawRay(character.transform.position, cameraDir, Color.blue); // Desired Vision
```

I tried doing `character.transform.forward = CameraDirection` and while I manage to get him to look in the correct direction the body rotates randomly (for instance sometimes the head is on the ground and the body above it).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This will make your character look at the Camera.

```
transform.LookAt(Camera.main.transform);
```

Comment: hi @FunctionR I just edited the question, I managed to get the direction the character should look towards. I'm just having problems rotating while keeping the body below the head.